# Is there a way to know the last account who modified NTFS rights on a folder?

Tags: powershell, directory, ntfs

I'm just did a PowerShell script listing all shared folders of all my servers + getting all NTFS rights of them.

Big lines:

```cs
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(OperatingSystem=*server*))" -Properties name |
    Select-Object name -ExpandProperty name >> "$path\servers.txt"

foreach ($_ in Get-Content "$path\servers.txt") {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Computer $_ |
        Format-Table path -AutoSize |
        Out-File "$path\Path\$_.txt"
}

foreach ($SharedFolder in $SharedFolders) {
    $lecteur = [int][char]'A'
    1..26 | ForEach-Object {
        $LR = [char]$lecteur
        $contenu = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$lgpath\$SharedFolder.txt").Replace("${LR}:", "\\$SharedFolder\$LR$").Replace("path", "").Replace("----", "").Replace("  ", "").Replace("\ ", "\")
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$lgpath\$SharedFolder.txt", $contenu)
        $lecteur++
    }
    (Get-Content "$lgpath\$SharedFolder.txt" | Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch '^\s*$'
    }) | Out-File "$lgpath\$SharedFolder.txt"
}

foreach ($SharedFolder in $SharedFolders) {
    $droits = foreach ($ligne in Get-Content "$lgpath\$SharedFolder.txt") {
        Get-NTFSAccess -Path "$ligne"
    }
    $droits |
        select Fullname, Account, AccessRights, InheritanceEnabled |
        Export-Csv "$Path\NTFS\NTFS_$SharedFolder.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
}
```

This is working fine for now but I'd like to have one more information: the last account that edited NTFS rights on each folder.

Comment: I don't think Windows stores this information by default, but you can enable [auditing on object access](https://www.petri.com/how-to-audit-permission-changes-on-windows-file-servers), which will generate [Event Log entries](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4670) you can query later (e.g. with `Get-WinEvent`).

Comment: Thx Boxdog ! It's a pretty good start. I'll dig on this an provide a complete result once I find out !!